# HTML Table or CSS? (Layout Issue)

Tags: html, css

I am struggling to understand how I can achieve the look I want with HTML tables/CSS while also having an Accordion,   I am getting data from multiple SharePoint lists and displaying it to the page in a JqueryUI Accordion however because it's essentially just a data dump I need to be able to add headers so the users know what data is what.   I have created a JS Fiddle of how I tried to do it,  with the issues explained below:

http://jsfiddle.net/7uv3m1fy/

The look I am trying to achieve is a set of headers across the top for the parent dataset, with the data from that set being the clickable part of the Accordion. These need the data to line up under the headers.   This is pretty much the entire issue I have,   they seem to be using only the first  of the HTML table on subsequent rows when I want the information to fill all of the columns (preferably with a way to match where the information goes to under it's header)

I honestly don't know enough about CSS or how I could achieve this using DIV's while still being able to get information to line up.

The biggest issue I have is that because the data populating these tables is called from SharePoint lists/views,  the number of columns is completely dynamic so I cannot hardcode column width/numbers.

Any suggestion of how I could do this using CSS or HTML or Both would be greatly appreciated.

below is the code I am currently using to generate this (C# as it's for a SharePoint WebPart)

```
try
        {
                if (parentItems.Count > 0)
                {
                    newHTML = newHTML + "<Table style='table-layout:fixed' width='100%'><tr>";

                    foreach (string fieldName in viewFields)
                    {
                        newHTML = newHTML + "<td>      " + parentList.Fields.GetFieldByInternalName(fieldName).Title + "</td>";
                    }
                    newHTML = newHTML + "</tr>";
                }
            }
        catch
        {
            newHTML = newHTML + "No Results Found";
        }
        foreach (SPListItem parentitem in parentItems)
        {
            newHTML = newHTML + "<tr class='yes' width='100%'><td> Parent:</td><td>" + parentitem.ID.ToString() + "</td></tr><tr width='100%'><td>";
            foreach (SPListItem childitem in childItems)
            {
                if (childitem[RelatedID].ToString() == parentitem.ID.ToString())
                {
                    newHTML = newHTML + "<div>" + childitem.ID.ToString() + "</div>";
                }
              }
            newHTML = newHTML + "</td></tr>";
        }
        newHTML = newHTML + "</table>";
    }
```

And in the webpart I am adding the following to call it:

```
<div id="accordion">
     <%= this.newHTML %>
</div>
```

I hope I have given enough information,   although the code above doesn't really relate to the question it will show you how I am trying to dynamically output the HTML to achieve my goal.

Happy to provide more info if you need it.

Regards,

Comment: Shaving off some of the text would probably attraction more attention, bud.

Comment: i'm not sure what you mean by some of the text?  That being said,  if you specifically want some more info,  i'm happy to provide it, just please be a bit more specific then text as i'm not sure what your refering to.    Thanks for your comment though!  - Edit:  sorry,  Shaving,  not showing.  I know what you mean.   Last post I put up they complained I didn't explain the problem well enough,  so I may have gone a bit overboard this time >.>

Comment: Achieving the right balance of information is tough sometimes.  I'll try to shorten your question after I'm finished with my work.

Comment: Perhaps instead of trying to use CSS to do all of this you can process your data on the backend.  I am not sure what your environment is, but if you have a .Net MVC Controller for example, you can parse the data into Header items `Parent Item 1 date operations` and that contains a List or IEnumeration of your `child items`.  The structure at that point is a simple css of parent and child.